# Finding a transition probability

Tags: stochastic-processes

My transition matrix is $$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
.4 & .3 & .3 \\
.3 & .2 & .5 \\
.7 & 0 & .3 
\end{array}\right) $$
So I'm asked for $P[X_3=1,\,X_2=1\,\lvert\,X_1=2]$ and:
$$\begin{eqnarray}P[X_3=1,\,X_2=1\,\lvert\,X_1=2]&=&\dfrac{P[X_1=2,\,X_2=1\,,\,X_3=1]}{P[X_1=2]}\\
 &=& \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^3P[X_1=2,\,X_2=1\,,\,X_3=1\,\lvert\,X_0=i]P[X_0=i]}{\sum_{i=1}^3P[X_1=2\,\lvert\,X_0=i]P[X_0=i]}\\
&=&\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^3P[X_0=i\,,\,X_1=2,\,X_2=1\,,\,X_3=1]}{\sum_{i=1}^3P[X_1=2\,\lvert\,X_0=i]P[X_0=i]}\\
&=&\ldots
\end{eqnarray}
$$
And the rest is easy to calculate. Am I right about the previous?

Comment: $$\mathbb P(X_3=1,X_2=1\mid X_1=2) = \mathbb P(X_3=1|X_2=1)\mathbb P(X_2=1\mid X_1=2)$$ and these probabilities may be computed by the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations.